# How many latin-square designs are orthogonal to this 4x4 latin square design?

Tags: matrices, puzzle, combinatorial-designs, latin-square, sudoku

[image: Latin Square]

Where this Latin Square is similar to sudoku, in which each row has one and only one of 1,2,3 and 4, and each column has one and only one 1,2,3 and 4.

Important: orthogonality means that the new latin-square design follows the same rules but no two numbers are in the same location in both the original latin-square and new latin-square. For example 1 is in the 1,1 position in the original. Any orthogonal latin-square design will have either a 2, 3, or 4 in the 1,1 position.

I came up with 18 for answer...

Comment: What does *orthogonal* mean in this context? How did you conclude that there are 18? Do you have reason to doubt that there are 18?

Comment: By brute force count, I get $45$, not $18$.

Comment: @MikePierce orthogonal means that no number (i.e. 1,2,3,4) appears in the same spot in a new square as in the original square, where every square design follows the same rules (i.e. only one of 1,2,3,4 in each row and column.

Comment: @quasi hmm... I started it by realizing that there are 3 possibilities for each spot in the possible new squares. for example, entry 1,1 can only be 2,3, or 4; likewise entry 1,2 can only be 1,3 or 4. Did you use this method? From there, I chose one number for entry 1,2 and said that however many possible square designs result from choosing this one number must be multiplied by 3, since there were 3 original numbers to choose from in entry 1,2.

Comment: @Hank Hopkins: I wrote a program to get the count.

Answer (score 2):

You're after the number of Latin squares which *avoid* the given Latin square, or equivalently the number of $4 \times 4 \times 2$ *Latin cuboids* with one layer given in the question.  (These are necessarily not orthogonal, in the standard sense of the word.)

I'm guessing there isn't anything better than a backtracking algorithm for this problem.  Here's some [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/) code to do that:

```
AvoidMe:=[[1,2,3,4],[2,1,4,3],[3,4,1,2],[4,3,2,1]];

L:=List([1..4],i->List([1..4],j->0));
count:=0;

AddEntry:=function(i,j)
  local k;

  for k in [1..4] do

    # want to avoid this
    if(AvoidMe[i][j]=k) then continue; fi;

    # symbol already used in row
    if(ForAny([1..4],j2->L[i][j2]=k)) then continue; fi;

    # symbol already used in column
    if(ForAny([1..4],i2->L[i2][j]=k)) then continue; fi;

    L[i][j]:=k;

    if(j=4) then
      if(i=4) then
        count:=count+1;
        Print(count," ",L,"\n");
      else
        AddEntry(i+1,1);
      fi;
    else
      AddEntry(i,j+1);
    fi;

    L[i][j]:=0;
  od;
end;;

AddEntry(1,1);
```

and it outputs

```
1 [ [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ] ]
2 [ [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 1, 3, 2, 4 ], [ 4, 2, 3, 1 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ] ]
3 [ [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 1, 4, 3, 2 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2, 1, 4 ] ]
4 [ [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 3, 2, 1, 4 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 4, 3, 2 ] ]
5 [ [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]
6 [ [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 4, 2, 3, 1 ], [ 1, 3, 2, 4 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ] ]
7 [ [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ] ]
8 [ [ 2, 3, 4, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 4, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ] ]
9 [ [ 2, 3, 4, 1 ], [ 1, 4, 3, 2 ], [ 4, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 3, 2, 1, 4 ] ]
10 [ [ 2, 3, 4, 1 ], [ 3, 2, 1, 4 ], [ 4, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 4, 3, 2 ] ]
11 [ [ 2, 3, 4, 1 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 4, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]
12 [ [ 2, 4, 1, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 1, 4, 2 ] ]
13 [ [ 2, 4, 1, 3 ], [ 1, 3, 2, 4 ], [ 4, 2, 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1, 4, 2 ] ]
14 [ [ 2, 4, 1, 3 ], [ 4, 2, 3, 1 ], [ 1, 3, 2, 4 ], [ 3, 1, 4, 2 ] ]
15 [ [ 2, 4, 1, 3 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 3, 1, 4, 2 ] ]
16 [ [ 3, 1, 4, 2 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 4, 1, 3 ] ]
17 [ [ 3, 1, 4, 2 ], [ 1, 3, 2, 4 ], [ 4, 2, 3, 1 ], [ 2, 4, 1, 3 ] ]
18 [ [ 3, 1, 4, 2 ], [ 4, 2, 3, 1 ], [ 1, 3, 2, 4 ], [ 2, 4, 1, 3 ] ]
19 [ [ 3, 1, 4, 2 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 4, 1, 3 ] ]
20 [ [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ] ]
21 [ [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3, 2, 4 ], [ 4, 2, 3, 1 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ] ]
22 [ [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 4, 2, 3, 1 ], [ 1, 3, 2, 4 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ] ]
23 [ [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ] ]
24 [ [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 4, 3 ], [ 2, 1, 3, 4 ] ]
25 [ [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1, 3, 4 ], [ 1, 2, 4, 3 ] ]
26 [ [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]
27 [ [ 3, 4, 2, 1 ], [ 4, 3, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ] ]
28 [ [ 3, 4, 2, 1 ], [ 4, 3, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2, 4, 3 ], [ 2, 1, 3, 4 ] ]
29 [ [ 3, 4, 2, 1 ], [ 4, 3, 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1, 3, 4 ], [ 1, 2, 4, 3 ] ]
30 [ [ 3, 4, 2, 1 ], [ 4, 3, 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]
31 [ [ 4, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3, 4, 1 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ] ]
32 [ [ 4, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 4, 3, 2 ], [ 2, 3, 4, 1 ], [ 3, 2, 1, 4 ] ]
33 [ [ 4, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 3, 2, 1, 4 ], [ 2, 3, 4, 1 ], [ 1, 4, 3, 2 ] ]
34 [ [ 4, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3, 4, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]
35 [ [ 4, 3, 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ] ]
36 [ [ 4, 3, 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 4, 3 ], [ 2, 1, 3, 4 ] ]
37 [ [ 4, 3, 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1, 3, 4 ], [ 1, 2, 4, 3 ] ]
38 [ [ 4, 3, 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4, 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]
39 [ [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ] ]
40 [ [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 4, 3, 2 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 3, 2, 1, 4 ] ]
41 [ [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 2, 1, 4 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 1, 4, 3, 2 ] ]
42 [ [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ] ]
43 [ [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2, 4, 3 ], [ 2, 1, 3, 4 ] ]
44 [ [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1, 3, 4 ], [ 1, 2, 4, 3 ] ]
45 [ [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ], [ 3, 4, 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1, 4, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]
```